# What does "database is just a namespace" mean in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I read this line in a book called **"MongoDb in Action"** and i didnt quite understand what does it mean . **"Unlike the usual overhead that databases produce in the SQL world, databases in MongoDB are just namespaces to distinguish between collections.**"

Comment: Did the author offer any context for that statement? Did (s)he mention provide any examples of "the usual overhead that databases produce in the SQL world"? In MongoDB a database doesn't really have any state **of its own**, instead it's just a grouping of collections. Perhaps this is what the author is referring to. However, on the face of it the statement you quoted would certainly benefit from additional context.

Comment: No, he doesnt provide any context or example  to the sentence.

Comment: Well, even in MongoDB, you can define user access permissions on the database level, so there is some state associated to it. I also don't know if the overhead in the SQL world for having a database/schema is all that high, either. I guess a takeaway would be that a "database" is a logical construct, does not imply a separate physical structure (different files on disk, different server instance, need for different connection etc) that would need to be set up for it.

Answer (score 0):

Form documentation -

> The namespace is a combination of the database name and the name of
>   the collection or index, like so:
>   [database-name].[collection-or-index-name]. All documents belong to a
>   namespace.